# Does Android INSTALL_REFERRER intent get sent on app update?

Tags: android, google-play, referrer

Or is it only for install? Does Play treat them the same?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to Localytics, [the intent is fired once](http://www.localytics.com/docs/android-market-campaign-analytics/) before the application launches for the first time:

> Android will fire an intent called:
>   com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER during the application install
>   process. This occurs before the application is launched for the first
>   time.

Comment: Just an addition to @David's comment. `com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER` is sent on first launch on devices running Android 3.2 and above.

Comment: Would this intent also get sent on a reinstall?  That is.  If the user uninstalls your app.  Then possibly they click on a referral link to Google Play (such as a reengagement campaign you run), and reinstall the app.  Or is the intent only sent on the first install?

Comment: @BryantHarris It will be fired on reinstall

Answer (score 0):

INSTALL_REFERRER intent only work on app launch very first time from the app store, and you can use like bellow sample

```
public class ReferrerReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    String referrer;
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        final String action = intent.getAction();

        if (action != null && TextUtils.equals(action, "com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER")) {
            try {
                referrer = intent.getStringExtra("referrer");
                Log.d("REFERRER","ReferrerReceiver. "+referrer);
                Toast.makeText(context, "ReferrerReceiver. "+referrer, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            }
    }
}
```